# Como hacer mas "ordenado" c# sql

Tags: mysql, c#, sql-server

estoy haciendo un programa y para actualizar la base de datos en MySql uso esto

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-BA82S6N;Initial Catalog=mtest;Integrated Security=True")) {
    cn.Open();
    string modificar = "update humano set nombre ='"+nombrea.Text+"', apellido ='"+apellidoa.Text+"', sexo ='"+sexoa.Text+"' where dni ="+dnia.Text+"";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(modificar, cn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Soy nuevo en esto de c# y base de datos pero sé que se puede de hacer una forma mas ordenada ya que para insertar datos uso

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-BA82S6N;Initial Catalog=mtest;Integrated Security=True")) {
    string sql_insert = "INSERT into humano(nombre,apellido,dni,sexo) VALUES (@nombre,@apellido,@dni,@sexo)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql_insert,cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", txtApellido.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni",dni.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo",cbSexo.SelectedItem);        
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

¿Hay una forma similar de usar `Parameters.AddWithValue` en un update en lugar de concatenar con '"++"'?

Comment: Hay bastantes respuestas en el [sitio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15246246)

Comment: Y la principal respuesta, exactamente igual al insert... en el insert usas parametros con nombre, en el update, haces lo mismo.. pones los placeholder y luego llenas los parametros...

Comment: Podrías utilizar [interpolación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) $"update humano set nombre ='{nombrea.Text}', apellido ='{apellidoa.Text}', sexo ='{ sexoa.Text}' where dni = {dnia.Text}". Es posible que tu pregunta sea cerrada por estar basada en opiniones.

Comment: La interpolación sigue estando abierta a inyección SQL y debe evitarse.